# Nodejs does not recognize my server.js paths

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, path

I'm trying to run the yarn start_dev command inside my main directory `C:\Users \THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel`

However when doing this it starts to give error in my "`process.env.DATABASE_URL`" as if it did not recognize my "`dotenv`" that is in the "`environment`" folder!

```
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\ DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel

C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js: 428
    throw new MongooseError ('The `uri` parameter to` openUri () `must be a +
    ^
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to` openUri () `must be a string, got" undefined ". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect ()` or `mongoose.createConnection ()` is the string.
    at new MongooseError (C: \Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\ NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\mongoose\lib\ error\mongooseError.js: 13:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\ DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\ mongoose\lib\connection.js: 428:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\ NEORIS \ ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\mongoose\lib\ index.js: 270: 15)
```

If I enter the url directly on my server.js it starts to give errors in my consign:

```
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT \NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel
! Entity not found C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\routes
! Entity not found C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ ALIANSCE \ aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\controllers
SERVER ROLLING IN PORT 3000: ')
```

But if I run the nodemon from the directory where the start.js is, it works: `C: \Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\app\backend\src\start.js`

**I would like to know why this happens and how to solve it, because I'm trying to upload the server to Heroku and it's not running, probably because of the same problem running `yarn start_dev`!**

**MY DIRECTORIES**
[image]

**SERVER.JS**

```
const express  = require('express');
const dotenv   = require('dotenv');
const morgan   = require('morgan');
const consign  = require('consign');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

class Application {
    constructor(){
        this.express  = express();
        this.dotenv   = dotenv.config({ path: './environment/.env' });
        this.morgan   = morgan('dev');
        this.consign  = consign();
        this.mongoose = mongoose;
        this.nunjucks = nunjucks;

        // INICIALIZA AS FUNÇÕES AUTOMATICAMENTE
        this.initDatabase();
        this.initMiddlewares();
        this.initConsign();
        this.initViews();

    }

    initDatabase(){ 
        this.mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
            useCreateIndex:  true,
            useNewUrlParser: true
        });
    }

    initMiddlewares(){
        this.express.set('view engine', 'njk');

        this.express.use(express.static('../../app/frontend'));
        this.express.use(express.json());
        this.express.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        this.express.use(this.morgan);
    }

    initConsign(){
        this.consign.include('./routes').then('./controllers').into(this.express);
    }

    initViews(){
        this.nunjucks.configure('./views/pages', {
            watch:      true, // SOMENTE PARA DESENVOLVIMENTO
            express:    this.express,
            autoescape: true
        });
    }

}

module.exports = new Application().express;
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "author": "THIAGO DE BONIS CARVALHO SAAD SAUD",
  "scripts": {
    "start_dev": "nodemon app/backend/src/start.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.5",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.1",
    "nunjucks": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the dotenv folder path set the absolute path.

```
this.dotenv   = dotenv.config({ path: require('path').join(__dirname, './environment') });
```